# Problem During showing of ContextMenuStrip in XtraGridview control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, contextmenustrip

I'm having one `ContextMenustrip` & `DevExpress XtraGridView`. And i shown the ContextMenustrip to the user when user right clicks on the  XtraGridView, for that i used `XtraGridView's MouseDown()` event. Issue of this application is that when my gridview contains minimum rows then it shows the some empty space at the end of the Gridview. And i don't want to show the ContextMenustrip in that empty space of the XtraGridView when user right click on the gridview. I just want to show the  ContextMenustrip  at selected row position only.
Is this possible to avoid this problem?

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use slightly different approach.  Handle the GridView's [PopupMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event as shown below to make certain that your menu is open only when it is necessary.

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e) {
            if(e.HitInfo.HitTest ==  GridHitTest.RowCell)    {
                e.Allow == false;
                // your code to show menu
            }
        }
```